# Python variable assignment between different methods

Tags: python, class

I would like to define a class variable in Python and then modify its value calling two different methods in this way:

```
class MyClass:   
    # Variable x definition
    nonlocal x
    
    def Method1():
        nonlocal x
        x = 1
        print('X VALUE: ', x)
        
    def Method2():
        nonlocal x
        print('X VALUE BEFORE NEW ASSIGNMENT: ', x)
        x = 2
        print('X VALUE NEW ASSIGNMENT: ', x)
        
c = MyClass()
c.Method1()
c.Method2()
```

I get this error at line 10:
*nonlocal x 'SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'x' found'.*
What's wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: A simple class variable would seem like a better solution for this isolated example.

Comment: Even if `MyClass` were a function rather than a class, you would only use `nonlocal` in the two nested functions to refer to a variable outside their scope, not in the function whose variable is being accessed. (You would still need to ensure that `x` was actually defined so that `nonlocal` would know which scope contained `x`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you try to do, since you give the functions no input the values of x will always be the same but see this:

```
class MyClass:   
    # Variable x definition
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
    
    def Method1(self):
        self.x = 1
        print('X VALUE: ', self.x)
        
    def Method2(self):
        print('X VALUE BEFORE NEW ASSIGNMENT: ', self.x)
        self.x = 2
        print('X VALUE NEW ASSIGNMENT: ', self.x)
        
c = MyClass()
c.Method1()
c.Method2()
c.Method2()
```

output:

```
X VALUE:  1
X VALUE BEFORE NEW ASSIGNMENT:  1
X VALUE NEW ASSIGNMENT:  2
X VALUE BEFORE NEW ASSIGNMENT:  2
X VALUE NEW ASSIGNMENT:  2
```

Answer (score 1):

`nonlocal` only works in nested functions. For top-level methods like this, you could just use `global`.

But it would seem to make more sense in this case to make `x` a static/class attribute instead.

Unrelated to your question, calls to your two methods will fail because you didn't declare them with the `self` parameter.